# How to make secure Date setter methods

Tags: java, date

How to make Date setter methods secure. Is it the below approach correct?

```
public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        birthDate = (Date)birthDate.clone();
}
```

Thanks
Jai

Comment: Here is a `NullPointerException` waiting to happen.

Comment: I'd rather use `new Date(birthDate.getTime())`, as I don't really like `clone()`. But @defaultlocale is right: NPE is just round the corner, waiting to strike...

Comment: What do you call secure? You just want a deep copy? Then this is ok, but you'll have to check for null indeed.

Comment: I would recommend [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) and its immutable `DateTime` as replacement of standard java `Date` class.

Comment: You should generally avoid `clone()` altogether, see here: [Copy Constructors vs Cloning](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is an object type, but it is mutable which means once a `date` object is created, it can be changed. `Date` class implements `clone()` from object class. so, it's always better to create setter method with cloning.

```
public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {  
    this.birthDate = (Date) birthDate.clone();  
}  

public Date getBirthDate() {  
    return (Date) this.birthDate.clone();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use `this.birthDate = new Date (birthDate.getTime ())`.  In this case you know for sure what will happen.

Comment: Not possible...since there is no Date(new Date()) constructor

Comment: @Jai Yes, I noticed it and thus changed to `new Date (birthDate.getTime ())`.